# Axis Function in R with tck and col.tick as parameters

Tags: r, axis

When using `axis(2, col='grey',tck=1,col.tick='grey')` The inner line of the plot turns grey but the ticks are still black. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default plot will have black tick marks. You probably need to drop the axis first and then add the tick marks again:

```
plot(1:10,yaxt="n")
axis(2, col.tick='grey')
axis(2, tck=1, col.tick='grey')
```